# Is there a way to suppress warnings on the D8 Status Report page?

Tags: status-messages, log-messages

On my D8 status report (admin/reports/status) I have warnings about an issue I might wish to ignore. Is there any way to suppress the warnings on that report page once I have seen them and made my decision?

If it matters, the warnings are about using a CDN instead of installing libraries locally with YAML Form, which produces a wall of ten yellow warning rows in my Status Report. If we decide to continue using the CDNs instead of installing, we'd like to not see those warnings taking over so much real estate on the Status Report page in the future.

Comment: I think this is reasonable request so I created this ticket (https://www.drupal.org/node/2825278) in the YAML Form module's issue queue.

Comment: That's cool @jrockowitz, thank you. I'm watching the issue now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no [hook_requirements_alter](https://www.drupal.org/node/309040) yet. As a workaround you may [override](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services) system manager service which is responsible for invoking that hook.

*src/SystemManager.php*

```
namespace Drupal\example;

use Drupal\system\SystemManager as DefaultSystemManager;

/**
 * System Manager Service.
 */
class SystemManager extends DefaultSystemManager {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function listRequirements() {
    // Suppress some unwanted warnings on Status report page.
    return array_filter(parent::listRequirements(), function ($requirement) {
      return $requirement['title'] != t('The message about CDN.');
    });
  }

}
```

*src/ExampleServiceProvider.php*

```
namespace Drupal\example;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;

/**
 * Overrides the system manager service to suppress some warnings.
 */
class ExampleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $container->getDefinition('system.manager')
      ->setClass('Drupal\example\SystemManager');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The controller for this route gathers up all the data reported by [`hook_requirements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_requirements/8.2.x) from the `SystemManager` service method [`listRequirements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!src!SystemManager.php/function/SystemManager%3A%3AlistRequirements/8.2.x) which is used to build its theme array.

There's no entry point into that process through the Drupal API's except through the theme layer. A module could evoke [`hook_preprocess_status_report()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) to alter the data in `$requirements` variable used to render the page.

This method would require you to alter the markup to provide UI element to capture the preference, store it, then use it to remove it from the `$requirements` array in future requests.

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_status_report(&$variables) {
  // @TODO: processing logic for $variables['requirements']
}
```